# HTML: Set scroll on div table-row

Tags: html, css

Hello i try to set scroll in .chat .body (overflow-y: scroll), i try every code but not work.

thanks in advance !
////////////////////////////////////////

Code:

```
<div class="chat">
    <div class="head"></div>
    <div class="body">
        <table border="0" width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td align="left" width="40">
                        <img src="http://www.exclutips.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/08/wordpress-custom-user-avatar.png" style="
                            width: 32px;
                            height: 32px;
                            display: block;
                            border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
                            cursor: pointer;
                            ">
                    </td>

                    <td align="left" width="136">
                        <div class="user-name">User Name</div>
                    </td>

                    <td align="right">
                        <span class="online-icon"></span>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
    <div class="footer">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Search">
    </div>
</div>


<style type="text/css">

    * { font-family: "Segoe UI"; }

    html {
        font-size: 100%;
        -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
        -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;
        height: 100%;
    }

    body {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        background: #F2F2F2;
        height: 100%;
    }

    input, select {
        display: block;
        width: 100%;
        padding: 5px;
        outline: none;
        border-width: 1px;
        border-style: solid;
        border-radius: 0;
        background: #fff;
        font-size: 12px;
        color: #6B6B6B;
        appearance:normal;
        -moz-appearance:none;
        -webkit-appearance:none;
        border-color: #BDBDBD;
    }

    div, textarea, input, select, button, a { box-sizing: border-box; -moz-box-sizing: border-box; }

    .chat {
        display: table;
        border-left: 1px solid #ccc;
        position: fixed;
        height: 100%;
        top: 0;
        right: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        width: 200px;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        background: #E1E1E1;
    }
    .chat .head {
        display: table-row !important;
        height: 52px;
    }
    .chat .body {
        overflow-y: scroll;
        display: table-row;
        height: 100% !important;
    }
    .chat .body table {
        cursor: pointer;
        padding: 5px;
    }
    .chat .footer {
        display: table-row !important;
    }
</style>
```

Check demo here: http://chatiiii.hol.es/default.php

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Automatically scroll down chat div](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25505778/automatically-scroll-down-chat-div)

Comment: @zurfyx not thisss ! i just want to set scroll

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `jQuery` to set `.body` height :

```
* {  
    box-sizing:border-box;
    ...
}

.chat {
    display: block;
    ...
}

.chat .head {
    height: 52px;
    ...
}

.chat .body {
    overflow-y: auto;
    ...
}
```

and jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    setSize();
    $(window).on('resize',setSize);
});

function setSize(){
    var CH = $('.chat').height(),
        HH = $('.chat .head').height(),
        FH = $('.chat .footer').height();
    $('.chat .body').height(CH-HH-FH);
}
```

see full example [here](https://jsfiddle.net/uj15o5gs/).

Answer (score 0):

Remove `display: table-row;` from `.chat .body`.

Comment: When remove, display: table-row height is not 100%; check demo here: http://chatiiii.hol.es/default.php;

Answer (score 0):

use this style for .chat .body class , but you should duplicate user table in html until it come more than page's height , then you can see scroll comes.

```
.chat .body {
    overflow-y: scroll;
    height: 80%;
}
```

You should remove display: table-row , and also give a height less than 100% .

Comment: No is not 80% also not work 100%, see screenshot http://image.prntscr.com/image/1547176c553f4992ac0e22a4a59fe564.png

Comment: @ErollKrasniqi ok that's fine i think it is solved !?

Comment: Kasra Asheghi no bro

Comment: duplicate table tag for 10-15 time (user table in html) , you will see scrollbar with my code.