# Keep scroll bar at the bottom of a div including a v-for?

Tags: html, css, vue.js

I am building a chat app. In the chat window, the chat goes from top to bottom, with old messages appearing at the top. There is a scroll bar when the messages go passed the div max-height.

The messages are loaded in using a Vue v-for. What is the best way to make it scroll the user to the bottom of the chat when they send/receive a message?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Automatically scroll down chat div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25505778/automatically-scroll-down-chat-div)

Comment: Or this: [Scroll to bottom of div?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/270612/scroll-to-bottom-of-div)